# Destructive file in php

Tags: php, laravel

Today my site is blocked  because of a distructive php file named "as.php" . I uploaded program about 1 years ago and there have been no problem since yesterday . why this file is located in program folder . I used  php 5.6 and laravel 5.2 . What could have happened? generally What alternatives can lead to this? how can I prevent from this problem ? "as.php" is distructive file that is  located in ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/util/php/as.php . Any reply is appreciated . thanks

Comment: Blocked where? How? By whom? When was the file added? What does it contain? By the path you posted it looks like it's a part of PHPUnit. Have you checked if it's a valid PHPUnit file? Maybe a false positive? We can't really say what happened since we can't evaluate/check anything on your server. A common practice is also to only require PHPUnit as a dev-package (and not loaded in production environments).

Comment: "blocked" means what exactly? What kind of "destructive" behaviour are you seeing? Please describe the problem more clearly. It doesn't look like "as.php" is likely to be part of PHPUnit, according to https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/master/src/Util/PHP . But I could be wrong. Are you saying this file has suddenly appeared, or has it been there the whole time? What is the content of it? You've left a lot of gaps in the explanation.

Comment: PHP 5.6 is a long time out of support (it was already a long time out of support when you uploaded your program 1 year ago), please upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: Who blocked your site ? The hosting company ?

Comment: Laravel 5.2 also isn't providing security fixes since late 2016. The latest stable version now is 8.78. If you're working with outdated software, it is just a matter of time before your website is compromised. It might be worth reading [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: I was going to suggest the same link as Ivar. It's a very useful guide.

Comment: thanks all . My site is blocked by hosting company as they said an infected file (that i specified its location) puts pressure on server . I did not directly add that file because I use framework (laravel) and most of files are added automatically and do not know when this file had been added . the content of "as.php" is  only "404 : Not found" that seems be useless .

Comment: Is that "404 : Not found" the actual content of the script file - or the output you see when you request the script in your browser ...?

Comment: the actual content of that file

Comment: Really? If you open the file in a text editor, it just contains the text "404 Not Found" and nothing else? In that case, it's hard to see how it's malicious, but how it got there might be a cause for concern, still.

Comment: hosting company sent a report "scan Message: known exploit = [fingerprint match]PHP upload Exploit[P0898] . any idea?

Comment: No. They should be giving you proper, specific details. Or try googling it. But you haven't answered my question.

Comment: If I open the file in a text editor, it just contains the text "404 Not Found" and nothing else . hosting company quarantine as.php file as its report , and the error message is that i mentioned .

Comment: Ok. Well then it may be that this particular file is harmless by itself, but it does appear you may have a vulnerability (or vulnerabilities) which allows someone else to upload files onto your server when they shouldn't. Clearly that loophole needs to be closed, before something more problematic gets uploaded. We can't really assist you with investigating that, other than to point you in the direction of general guidance such as the excellent link Ivar posted.

Comment: thank you my friend